# Show 1-in-3 SAT

Tags: np-complete

1-in-3 SAT is the set of 3CNF formulas with no negated variables such that
there is a satisfying assignment that makes exactly one variable in each clause true. Show 1-in-3 SAT is NP-complete

Plan on doing a reduction from 3SAT.

My confusion arises from the "no negated variables". You need some way of representing negated variables. How do you do that? I can do the reduction from 3SAT to 1-in-3 SAT without the restraint that there are no negated variables. I'm just not sure how to do it with this constraint.

Comment: The 1-in-3 part represents the negated variables; 1 is true, the other two are negated.

Answer (score 4):

*My confusion arises from the "no negated variables".* This is the point of the question. You need to figure out a way to simulate negated variables.

Hint: One way is using a "gadget" that forces $b = \lnot a$ for some variables $a,b$. You can start by coming up with a way of forcing certain auxiliary variables to be True or False.

Comment: YuvalFilmus Does this work: for some clause that has a,b,c. we take the variable (e.g.) and create a new clause: (a v d_x v d_x). d_x is a dummy variable that is forced to be fals

Comment: That forces $d_x$ to be false and $a$ to be true, which is not quite what you wanted, but a good start. This gives a way of ensuring some variables are false and some are true. Now how can you use it to express something like $a \leftrightarrow \lnot b$?

Comment: if the clause is (x v -y v z), then we change it to: (x v y v z) and (d_y v y v y).

Comment: That doesn't quite work - it forces $y$ to be negative. You want $y$ to be able to have both values. But if you had two clauses $(y \lor \cdots)$ and $(\lnot y \lor \cdots)$, you want to replace them with $(y^+ \lor \cdots)$ and $(y^- \lor \cdots)$, where $y^+$ and $y^-$ have opposite values.

Comment: If the clause is (x v -y v z) don't you want to force why to be negative?

Comment: I suggest you think it over and come up with an answer yourself.